# scroll bar go behind the div

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

Salaam,

I want to make an HTML layout like below:

```
+----------------------+-----+
|       upSide         |     |
|----------------------|     |
|                      |right|
|                      |side |
|                      |     |
|      mainSide        |     |
|                      |     |
|                      |     |
+----------------------+-----+
```

Some thing like this:

```
<div id="rightSide"></div>
<div id="mainFrame">
    <div id="upside"></div>
    <div id="mainSide"></div>
</div>
```

where I want to #upSide be over the #mainSide, in other word when you scrolling the #mainFrame, elements which in the #mainSide be visible at behind the #upSide, when the #upSide's background is transparent(e.g. background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.35)).

Problem is when I set some things like below:

```
#upSide{
    position:fixed;
    width: 80%;
}
#rightSide{
    width:20%;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
}
#mainFrame{
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

all things true, but the scrollbar(which in the #mainFrame) goes behind the #upSide.
What's your suggestion for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

The scroll bar goes behind #upSide because of the position:fixed that you added.

Try something like this.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    #upSide{
        height:200px;
        width: 80%;
        background:blue;
    }
    #mainSide{
        height:800px;
        width: 80%;
        background:green;
    }
    #rightSide{
        width:20%;
        height:800px;
        float:right;
        position:relative;
        background:red;
    }
    #mainFrame{
        height:800px;
        width: 80%;
        overflow:auto;
        background:yellow;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="rightSide"></div>
    <div id="mainFrame">
        <div id="upside"></div>
        <div id="mainSide"></div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: I want #upSide stick to top of the page. It should always be visible. Even when user scroll down.